# In Unity 4.7.2, the .js file in the StreamingAssets folder is incorrectly recognized as a game script,but not appear in Unity 5.3.5f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, uniwebview

I would like to use UniWebView load local html5 page, so I put the html5 file into the StreamingAssets folder, but html5. Js file is recognized as Unity4.7.2 game script, resulting in the game can not be compiled. But the same operation does not appear in Unity5.3.5f1. I would like to ask how can I do in Unity4.7.2 correctly import Html5 web resources?